# GeneralException when using Replace and insertText in a Word JS Add-In

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-addins

I am trying replace all instances of "[[original]]" with "replaced" and have gotten an error with little meaning to me.

My confusion is why there is a general exception as I can't see why this code would raise an error. It looks similar to that in similar StackOverflow posts.

```
(2) ['inserted', 'the']
Found [[inserted]] 1 times.
Found [[the]] 1 times.
Error: GeneralException: GeneralException
Debug info: {"code":"GeneralException","message":"GeneralException","errorLocation":"Range.insertText","statement":"var insertText = v.insertText(...);","surroundingStatements":["var v = context.root._getObjectByReferenceId(\"021!00000006\");","// >>>>>","var insertText = v.insertText(...);","// <<<<<","// Instantiate {insertText}"],"fullStatements":["Please enable config.extendedErrorLogging to see full statements."]}
Error: GeneralException: GeneralException
Debug info: {"code":"GeneralException","message":"GeneralException","errorLocation":"Range.insertText","statement":"var insertText = v.insertText(...);","surroundingStatements":["var v = context.root._getObjectByReferenceId(\"021!00000009\");","// >>>>>","var insertText = v.insertText(...);","// <<<<<","// Instantiate {insertText}"],"fullStatements":["Please enable config.extendedErrorLogging to see full statements."]}
```

The code causing the issue is as follows:

```
function replaceInDocument(original, replaced) {
        original = "[[" + original + "]]";
        Word.run(function (context) {
            var options = Word.SearchOptions.newObject(context);
            options.matchCase = false;
            var tagResults = context.document.body.search(original, options);
            context.load(tagResults, 'text');
            return context.sync()
                .then(function () {
                    console.log("Found " + original + " " + tagResults.items.length + " times.");
                    for (let v = 0; v < tagResults.items.length; v++) {
                        tagResults.items[v].insertText(replaced, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
                    }
                }).then(context.sync);
        }).catch(errorHandler); 
    }
```

We tried running it on another computer and somehow it runs there, but not on my computer. I am at a loss.